# Django forms with instance of object

Tags: django, django-forms

How to create on one page multiple form with instance of each model object.
I have already created object of salon. And i need to render form with instance of all objects on one page.

**forms.py**

```
class SalonForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Salon
        fields = ('some_fields')
```

**views.py**

```
def salon_list(request):
    salons_list = Salon.objects.all()
    form = SalonForm()
    ctx = {
        'salons': salons,
        'form': form,
    }
    return render(request, 'template/list.html', ctx)
```

**list.html**

```
{% for salon in salons %}
    {{ salon }}
    {{ form }}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: i mean i need to render form with instance of each object.

Comment: Can you give a example

Comment: [Model formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **FormSet**.

```
from django.forms import modelformset_factory
```

[formset link](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/topics/forms/modelforms/#model-formsets/)

Comment: okay its worked, but also i need provide data from model(without form inputs), Like salon - name, can i somehow get this data? in formset

Comment: in view: add on top `salon = Salon.objects.filter(...` and extend  `{'formset': formset, 'salon': salon}`

Answer (score 0):

To put the  model formset solution together:

**forms.py**

```
class SalonForm(forms.ModelForm):

    class Meta:
        model = Salon
        fields = ('some_fields')
```

**views.py**

```
from django.forms import modelformset_factory

def salon_list(request):
    SalonFormSet = modelformset_factory(Salon, form=SalonForm)

    if request.method == 'POST':
    formset = SalonFormSet(request.POST)
        if formset.is_valid():
        formset.save()
    else:
        formset = SalonFormSet()

    return render(request, 'template/list.html', {'formset': formset})
```

**list.html**

```
<form method="post">
    {{ formset }}
</form>
```

The links for more Details (QuerySets, render each field individual ...) are already above.